# update all items in a list using function in python

Tags: python, list, function

Could you please tell what i'm doing wrong and how to fix it.

Thanks

I have a function.

```
def out(some_list):
    test_list = [1,2,3,4]
    result = []

    for i in some_list:
        if i == 1:
            test_list = [0,0,0,0]
        else:
            test_list = test_list

        result.append(test_list)

    return result
```

if we print it out it will return:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

I need to return

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4]]
```

Comment: What does `test_list = test_list` mean? Why are you doing this? It doesn't add anything to the code.

Comment: When I run this code, it doesn't return `[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]`. I get `[[1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]` instead. Please make sure your question is correct.

Comment: What's the value of `some_list`? If the first element is the value `1` then yes it will be `[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]`. You aren't checking if you are on the first index, you are checking if the value in `some_list` is `1`.

Comment: Can you show how you call the `out` function? Without it your example is not complete. Also the a brief explanation of logic behind your function. How should the input be transformed into the output? What has the 1 got to do with anything?

Comment: Please don't edit a question in a way that invalidates existing answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the list you are passing in this function has `1` as the value of the first element. For example:

```
out([1,2,3,4]) # ==> [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Going through your code step by step:

```
test_list = [1,2,3,4]
result = []

for i in some_list:           # The value of each element in some_list
    if i == 1:                # If the value is "1" set test_list: [0,0,0,0]
        test_list = [0,0,0,0]
    else:
        test_list = test_list # Otherwise set test_list to itself (doing nothing)

    result.append(test_list)
```

---

```
for i in some_list:
```

The for loop value of `i` is the value of the element you are on in `some_list`, it is not the index or position of the element we are on in the list (*as it appears this question intends*)

```
    if i == 1:
        test_list = [0,0,0,0]
```

If the value is `1`, then `test_list` will be set to `[0,0,0,0]`. Once this is hit only the value `[0,0,0,0]` will be appended to `result`. So if the first element is `1` then you will only see the value `[0,0,0,0]` in the result, otherwise you will see `[1,2,3,4]` until the loop hits where the value in the list `some_list` is `1`.

Here are some examples:

```
out([0,1,2,3]) # [[1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
out([1,2,3,4]) # [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
out([2,2,5,1]) # [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Hopefully this makes it more clear why you are getting that result.

---

**Edit**

In terms of your updated question whats happening here is that when you call `.append(fig)` is simply a copy of the reference to the `fig` in memory. Basically whenever it changes all the copies that you appended will change as well. There are two ways you can handle this, first would be have the variable `fig` be defined in the scope of your loop, this way it's a new and different variable on each loop:

```
 for i in test_list:
   fig = [2, 1]  # <== In the scope of the loop, so each fig is it's on variable
   ...
```

The second way is you could append `fig[:]`, which means it will copy the array `fig` as a new array and pass that in for `append`:

```
for i in test_list:

  if i == '0':
      fig[0] = off
      fig[1] = off
  elif i == '1':
      fig[0] = off
      fig[1] = on

  new_list.append(fig[:]) # <== Copy the array fig and append that value
```

Comment: Hi Spencer, thanks for your explanation but i need exactly to re-write test list depending on conditions

Comment: @Dmitriy_kzn Can you clarify what you mean by adding some more info in the question with clarification?

Comment: @Dmitriy_kzn I've updated my question on why that's happening. Basically it's holding the reference to `fig`, and because of that any time it changes all the previous appended items (being a reference) will change as well. Your last example you where actually creating a new variable `test_list` in the scope of your while loop, different that the one in the function scope.

Comment: Thanks Spencer, now it’s clear.  Many thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

It is because you set `test_list = [0,0,0,0]` 
so even in `test_list = test_list` it is keeping the result from setting it to `[0,0,0,0]`

try using

```
def out(some_list):
test_list = [1,2,3,4]
result = []

for i in some_list:
    if i == 1:
        result.append([0,0,0,0])
    else:
        result.append(test_list)

return result
```